# AmCharts - The same scale for both Axis

Tags: scale, axis, amcharts

I have Graph with 2 lines, each one have axis (left and right).
But Left axis depend of (for example) red data and has the max 100, Right depend of blue data and has max 10. Both lines looks like the same, but I want to have one scale for both lines. I mean if bigger max of them lines is 100, 100 should be max for both.

Sorry for my Eng.

Comment: Can you not just use one axis then if you want them both to be on the same scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to sync both axes is to use synchronizeWith setting in your secondary axis.

http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#synchronizeWith
http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#synchronizationMultiplier

Here's an example:

```
"valueAxes": [{
        "id":"v1",
        "axisColor": "#FF6600",
        "axisThickness": 2,
        "gridAlpha": 0.2,
        "axisAlpha": 1,
        "position": "left"
    }, {
        "id":"v2",
        "axisColor": "#FCD202",
        "axisThickness": 2,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "axisAlpha": 1,
        "position": "right",
        "synchronizeWith": "v1",
        "synchronizationMultiplier": 1
    }],
```

Please remember that you need to set **synchronizationMultiplier** to **1** if you want both axes to use exactly the same scale.

Answer (score 1):

You can use synchronizeWith abd synchronizationMultiplier properties: http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#synchronizeWith

set axis1.synchronizeWith = axis2;
(or, if you are using JSON config, add some id property to first value axis and then set synchronizeWith:"axis1id",

and then set 
set synchronizationMultiplier to 1.